Simulation tool for beam propagation in bent multi mode fiber
I am trying to simulate a beam propagation in multi mode fiber, I am looking for simulation tool that can simulate a multi mode fiber one meter long. Also I would like to add bends to the fiber, so it would be able to simulate bent fibers.
I would like to retrieve one of the following:

Retrieve the transmission and reflection matrices of the fiber in the mode basis of a given fiber configuration.
Retrieve the transmission and reflection waves of the fiber, given a controlled input field.
Is there any tool that could fit my needs? or any other method that could be viable for this task.

Thanks!

It would be very useful if you’d also add what tools you’ve found/tried/rejected and for what reasons, so we don’t repeat any by accident.

I have tried using lumerical mode solver, but I didn't understand whether and how can I retrieve the transmission and reflection matrices in the mode basis(or even in the pixel basis if available), or how to control the input wave and retrieve the relected and transmitted wave.

You can have a look at https://wavefrontshaping.github.io/pyMMF/readme_link.html where there is all documentation on a multimode fiber propagation simulation in python available (with bent fiber taken in account).

@Aliceo Can I retrieve the reflection field or reflection matrix as well with this tool?

@DvirMarsh No idea. but the documentation seem quite complete
